# Auto generating if 3 columns is not empty

Tags: google-sheets

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>""&C2:C<>""&D2:D<>"","I"&+row(1:1000),""))`

When B2, C2 and D2, is not empty, A2 will generate I#.
However, I# auto generated to I1000 even B2, C2 and D2 are empty.
How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: post some code also, what you have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your formula to

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF( (B2:B<>"")*(C2:C<>"")*(D2:D<>""),"I"&+row(1:1000),))
```

and see if that works?